# how can I communicate (eg. run commands via write) with a child process when execv("/bin/sh", NULL) was called in C?

Tags: c, fork, x86-64

I am trying to make my program able to interact with another program which takes input. I tried that with `fork()` by executing `execv("/bin/sh", NULL)` in the child process. Now it should be replaced with the new process, `/bin/sh`. Now I want my parent process to communicate with `/bin/sh` like send commands. I tried that using pipes, but I guess I am doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd);
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0) {               // child code
    close(0);                  // close stdin fd
    dup(pipefd[0]);            // duplicate the pipe fd (will return 0)
    close(pipefd[1]);          // close the pipefd 1 (I dont need to write for child now)
    execv("/bin/sh", NULL);    // execute /bin/sh
  } else {                     // parent code
    close(1);                  // close stdout fd
    dup(pipefd[1]);            // duplicate the pipe fd (will return 1)
    close(pipefd[0]);          // close the pipefd 0 (I dont need to read right now)
  }

  write(0, "touch xxx\n", 10); // try to run a command with the parent process
  waitpid(-1, WNOHANG, 0);     // wait for the child to exit
}
```

I tried to write to stdin from the parent, because I thought `/bin/sh` takes input from stdin I can write to it. Sadly my command isn't executed. After that I can enter something, but it does nothing. Here is the output of strace:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7fffffffe870 /* 41 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x555555559000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffffffe710) = -1 EINVAL (Das Argument ist ungültig)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=210476, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 210476, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7f92000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`|\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 80, 848) = 80
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0T\246\344\4\347\334\35\347\301CJ\0\267\261\2552"..., 68, 928) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2154488, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7f90000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 1884632, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7dc3000
mmap(0x7ffff7de9000, 1359872, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7ffff7de9000
mmap(0x7ffff7f35000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x172000) = 0x7ffff7f35000
mmap(0x7ffff7f81000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7ffff7f81000
mmap(0x7ffff7f87000, 33240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7f87000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7dc1000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7f91580) = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7f81000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x555555557000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7ffb000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7f92000, 210476)          = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ffff7f91850) = 29114
close(1)                                = 0
dup(4)                                  = 1
close(3)                                = 0
write(0, "touch xxx\n", 10touch xxx
)             = 10
wait4(-1,
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Changed it, but still doesn't work. I'll update the post

Comment: `execv("/bin/sh", NULL);`: `/bin/sh` isn't likely to appreciate being called with its argv vector set to NULL.  At the very least it should have an `argv[0]` which is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @NateEldredge `/bin/sh` is fine with a NULL argv

Comment: Also you have the arguments to `waitpid` mixed up.  You should get a compiler warning for that. ([checking](https://godbolt.org/z/nvrv64)) Oh, you don't because you didn't include `<sys/wait.h>`, so the compiler doesn't know the argument types for `waitpid`.  But you do get an implicit declaration warning about *that*, and "implicit declaration" is a warning that you should treat as an error - don't even bother trying to run the code until you fix it.

Comment: If it is with your shell, that's lucky.  The documentation for `execv` actually forbids passing a null pointer as `argv`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Really, why was there no warning by the compiler showing up?

Comment: @BitFriends: For `execv`, or `waitpid`? I definitely get a compiler warning for the latter on GCC with no flags (`warning: passing argument 2 of ‘waitpid’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`). The former doesn't give a warning reliably because `NULL` is a legal argument to any function accepting a pointer from the language's point of view. The function may explode when it's handed a `NULL` pointer, but the compiler generally doesn't know that (aside from the occasional weird cases where the compiler performs some level of argument checking as a nicety, e.g. `printf`).

Comment: For `execv`, turn on `-Wall` and [you'll get one](https://godbolt.org/z/TMEa46), at least with gcc/glibc: `warning: null argument where non-null required`.  It requires some cooperation between the compiler and library headers, so not all combinations of compiler and library will give you a warning.

Comment: You should have `_exit(1)` after `execv` in case `execv` fails.

Comment: GCC since forever warns even without `-Wall`, for the code in your current question.  https://godbolt.org/z/76j974.  If you're not seeing the warning, use a better compiler or fix your dev env to not hide GCC's stdout / stderr.  Without the headers included, GCC4.x or earlier in C mode doesn't warn by default about implicit declarations (only with `-Wall`) because such old GCC defaults to C89 mode, not C99.  Older GCC still warns (with -Wall) with `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11`.  https://godbolt.org/z/E1jzdf.  But really you should always use -Wall, and use `strace ./a.out` to trace syscalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parent process (the `else` block) is closing and replacing fd `1`, corresponding to `stdout`, meaning writes to its own `stdout` will go to the `stdin` of the child. But you `write` to the *parent's* unmodified fd `0`, `stdin`.

Change the code so the parent writes to fd `1`, `stdout`, which is attached to the pipe that leads to the child's fd `0`, `stdin`.

There are other issues here as well (which compiling with any level of warnings enabled would make clear). Fix those, and this *should* work (assuming, as you state, your system is liberal in allowing `execv` to accept `NULL` as the second argument).

Comment: The OP should consider *not* redirecting the parent's standard output.  It is not necessary to do so to write to the pipe, and if the parent closes (all copies of) its original standard output then it no longer has that available for other uses, such as communicating with the user.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: True. I'm assuming this is some trivial exercise where they're simulating the behavior of shell pipes, e.g. `echo 'touch xxx' | /bin/sh` or the like, and replacing standard handles (so only the child is responsible for output to the original `stdout`) is part of the exercise. But yes, I agree that in the real world, there is rarely a reason to throw away the original `stdout` when you could just interact with the pipe's write fd directly while leaving the original `stdout` available (exception might be cases where some badly written API only writes to `stdout`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger when I read from that file descriptor, I recieve the data, but the data I recieve is then sent to the child. How can I only receive data?

Comment: @BitFriends: You're not being entirely clear on what is not working as expected. Your code as written could stand to close unused pipe handles more consistently (make sure *every* unused handle in both parent and child is closed; remember they need to be closed *separately* in parent and child). Make sure you're flushing if you're using the C stdio wrappers around your I/O, and perhaps explicitly close your fd `0` when you've finished writing, so the child knows not to expect anything further from it (assumes you want to wait for the child to exit, and it won't exit until its stdin is closed).